# Getting a button to blink when selected Java

Tags: java, swing

I have created a grid of buttons.  When a user clicks on a button it needs to blink.  I know I need a timer, I am just stuck on how to implement it so that it makes the button blink.  Below creates the grid and changes a button to yellow when clicked.

```
    private void showGrid(int gridSize) {

    gridPanel = new JPanel();
    gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(gridSize, gridSize));
    gridPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));

    buttons = new JButton[gridSize][gridSize];
    labels = new JLabel[gridSize][gridSize];

    for (int row = 0; row < gridSize; row++) {

        for (int col = 0; col < buttons[row].length; col++) {
            buttons[row][col] = new JButton();
            labels[row][col] = new JLabel();
            buttons[row][col].addActionListener(this);
            gridPanel.add(buttons[row][col]);

        }
    }
    contentPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();
    if(e.getSource() != newGame)
    {
        //HOW DO I GET THIS TO BLINK?
        btn.setBackground(Color.yellow);


    }
}
```

Comment: The [documentation for Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) has a pretty clear example.

Answer (score -1):

you can implement the same through thread

use

Thread.sleep(100);

then set previous color again.

Steps are provided .Hope you can implement.

Comment: First of all, you cannot sleep in the AWT event dispatch thead and expect your changes to be seen. Second, if you blink ten times per second, you will give your users epileptic seizures, or at least irritate them greatly.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044244/java-swing-blinking-button-sequence